# MongoDB - DBRef to a DBObject

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, dbref

Using Java ... not that it matters.

Having a problem and maybe it is just a design issue.

I assign "_id" field to all of my documents, even embedded ones.
I have a parent document ( and the collection for those ) which has an embedded document

So I have something like:

```
{ "_id" : "49902cde5162504500b45c2c" , 
  "name" : "MongoDB" , 
  "type" : "database" , 
  "count" : 1 , 
  "info" : { "_id" : "49902cde5162504500b45c2y", 
             "x" : 203 , 
             "y" : 102
           }
}
```

Now I want to have another document which references my "info" via a `DBRef`, don't want a copy.  So, I create a `DBRef` which points to the collection of the parent document and specifies the _id as  xxxx5c2y.   However, calling `fetch()` on the `DBRef` gives a NULL.

Does it mean that `DBRef` and `fetch()` only works on top level collection entry "_id" fields?

I would have expected that `fetch()` would consume all keys:values within the braces of the document .. but maybe that is asking too much.  Does anyone know??  Is there no way to create cross document references except at the top level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your DBRef _id references need to be to documents in your collection, not to embedded documents.

If you want to find the embedded document you'll need to do a query on `info._id` and you'll need to add an index on that too (for performance) OR you'll need to store that embedded document in a collection and treat the embedded one as a copy.  Copying is OK in MongoDB ... 'one fact one place' doesn't apply here ... provided you have some way to update the copy when the main one changes (eventual consistency).

BTW, on DBRef's, the official guidance says "Most developers only use DBRefs if the collection can change from one document to the next.  If your referenced collection will always be the same, the manual references outlined above are more efficient."

Also, why do you want to reference `info` within a document?  If it was an array I could understand why you might want to refer to individual entries but since it doesn't appear to be an array in your example, why not just refer to the containing document by its _id?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Ok, DBRef ... top level docs only.  I agree with your other comments re: copying, but if things do change and elaborat event model to update many locatons needs to be in place.  My example ( data model ) was not really representative of the problems model, it is a case where the "info" object is really a meta model in my problem sapce, which is being used for pattern analysis.  So, changes to the parent ( and sub docs of the parent ) need to update the meta model.  I cannot wholy embedd these as it will mean changes need to update millions of places.